# React Material-ui Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

After i implemented my application, i wanted to style it with Material UI.
When changing from html  to Material  i started recieving a warning when clicking select item:

`index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.`

**Initial code:**

```
<label htmlFor="newRole">Role</label>
        <select
          name="newRole"
          id="newRole"
          value={newUser.newRole}
          onChange={handleChangeNew}
        >
          <option value="0">Student</option>
          <option value="2">Professor</option>
          <option value="3">Secretary</option>
        </select>
```

**Material UI code:**

```
 <InputLabel shrink id="role-lbl"> Role </InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="role-lbl"
              name="newRole"
              id="newRole"
              value={newUser.newRole}
              onChange={handleChangeNew}
              // displayEmpty
              variant="filled"
            >
              <MenuItem value="0">Student</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="2">Professor</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="3">Secretary</MenuItem>
            </Select>
```

Comment: This seems an internal implementation detail of InputLabel component, you can probably just ignore it.
It is saying it is deprecated, not forbidden. This warning will never be displayed on production

Comment: Unfortunately even after deleting InputLabel i still get this deprecation error

Answer (score 1):

That is a little bit strange but I can not reproduce your warning. But as I faced it several times I can give you two advices how to fix it.

1. (not recommend) Just remove `<React.StrictMode>` wrapper on your `<App />`
2. [useRefs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). The idea might look like this:

```
import {InputLabel, MenuItem, Select} from "@material-ui/core";
import {useRef} from "react";

export default function Example3() {
    const nodeRef = useRef(null);
    
    function handleChangeNew(){
        console.log('changed');
    }

    return(
        <>
          <InputLabel shrink id="role-lbl"> Role </InputLabel>
            <Select
                noderef={nodeRef}
                labelId="role-lbl"
                id="newRole"
                value={newUser.newRole}
                onChange={handleChangeNew}
                // displayEmpty
                variant="filled"
            >
                <MenuItem value="0" ref={nodeRef}>Student</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="1" ref={nodeRef}>Professor</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="2" ref={nodeRef}>Secretary</MenuItem>
            </Select>
        </>
    )
}
```